# Precipitation occurred when adding vanilla extract to oak extract. What caused this?

Tags: solutions, precipitation

Sorry if this is a very obscure question, but I don't know where to ask it.

120ml of oak extract, made by soaking oak chips in ethanol, was added to a flask. At this point, the solution was very dark with zero precipitate. 13ml of vanilla extract, consisting of ethanol, water, vanilla, and corn sugar were added to the solution. This extract was also free of precipitate before being added. Immediately upon adding the vanilla extract, a large amount of precipitate fell out the solution. Can someone please explain what happened, and what fell out of solution?

Comment: Well, unless you want exact composition of precipitate, then it's rather simple imo - one extract was on almost pure ethanol other on diluted so you basically added water and lowered solubilities of most of compounds in this solution.

Comment: The oak extract was 95%, and the vanilla 35%. That would have only dropped it to a 89.1% strength. The amount of precipitate (it's about half the volume of the solution) made me think the small dilution wasn't the cause.

Comment: Also some of vanilla extract may precipitated as diff was much bigger for it. Main thing seems to be how much extracted stuff was it those extracts.